# Getting the matched number as well as the result

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex:

```
a_list = re.compile(r'\(\d+\)\s*\n').split(content)
```

Its working great to match lines with (number) in the end, however I need to get that number as well.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described on the [regular expressions documentation for Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), the split method on a regex splits the string that's being worked on by all matches of the regex pattern. Right now, your regex is capturing all matches that have a number at the end and splitting the string on that match. So a_list contains everything in every line containing a number except for the number and its surrounding parentheses (and optional space).

Assuming that you don't want to split all newlines (by just making your regex `'\n'`), you can use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) to only capture matches to the regex where another regex is preceding the match, but not include the matches for that second regex in the results. The format for that is `(?<!x)y` where all instances of y will be captured if and only if the x phrase is proceeding it, but the x phrase will not be included along with it.

The only problem with using a negative lookbehind in this situation is that it requires a fixed number of characters to be matched, but you have `\d+`, which could be any number of characters. Fortunately, you can just drop the `+` as well as the leading `\(` so that you check to see if there is at least one digit preceding your regex pattern so that we're just checking for `\d\)`; which works because we don't care if the line ends with `(10000)` or `(1)`.

Unfortunately, this would cause lines like `(abc123)` to be captured, which doesn't match the `\(\d+\)` regex you originally had. If you need to ensure that lines end with parentheses that only contain a multi-digit a number, you'll probably have to use multiple regex operations.

That does leave the problem of `\s*`, so you have two options. You can either create an or expression if you know how many spaces will be at the end, e.g. `(\d|\d\s)`, or you can just include the `\s*` in the match with the newline character, thus removing any trailing whitespace as well.

Assuming you take the latter option, your example would look like `(?<!\d\))\s*\n`, which will result in a_list containing all lines that include a number at the end being included, along with the number itself (and its surrounding parentheses).

Comment: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed the example so that the negative lookbehind uses a fixed width.

Comment: what about more than 1 digits or spaces?

Comment: I've revised the example so that there is an option for expressions where there is more than one space (which admittedly is a better way to do it than an or expression). It doesn't matter if there is more than one digit at the end of the line because the situation only involves splitting apart lines where there is some number at the end, regardless of the number of digits.

Comment: good job, and it's close, but still has bug. e.g. `re.compile(r'(?<!\(\d\))\s*\n').split("a(1)\nb(2) \nc(1x1)\nd")`

Comment: I see the problem. The c example has a letter in between the parentheses, which presumably the original poster doesn't want since he's going through the trouble of including the parentheses with his original regex of `\(\d+\)`. Without doing multiple regex operations, I'm not sure of a way to solve that problem. Is there some technique I'm not thinking of?

Comment: My answer solved the problem, maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

Using `split` function may need look-behind assertion, unfortunately look-behind requires fixed-width pattern(that's what @Thunderforge have tried). My solution takes use of `findall`:

```
re.findall(r'(.*?\(\d+\))\s*\n', content, re.S)
```

Notes:

- flag `re.S` makes the '.' match any character at all, including a
  newline
- `.*?` indicates the non-greedy match

But this solution still has flaws. If `content` doesn't end with digits and "\n", the last portion will be discarded. We can solve this problem by list comprehension or generator expression, namely:

```
[i or j for i, j in re.findall(r'(.*?\(\d+\))\s*\n|(.+)', content, re.S)]
```

or:

```
(i or j for i, j in re.findall(r'(.*?\(\d+\))\s*\n|(.+)', content, re.S))
```

Comment: Your solution is pretty good too. I guess that there is no perfect way to solve the user's problem with regexes and whichever the right solution is depends on what drawbacks they are willing to live with.